# How to query rows like IndexOf

Tags: android, sqlite

Table[id, data]
data is like this:

```
str[N]
```

where clause is like this:

```
strs = 'str1#str2#str3#str4#str5......'
```

if I split it with '#', I got a big array. Then I wrote like this:

```
select * from Table where data in(str1,str2,str3,str4,str5).......
```

The length may be very large. It's too slow. I just wanna do:

```
select * from Table where 'str1#str2#str3#str4#str5......'.indexOf(data)!=-1
```

Thanks!

Comment: did you try to create an index for the field you are running the query?

Comment: I think the IN clause can not use the index.... As I know sql can only tell equals instead of IN or LIKE

Comment: from http://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html 

If an index is created using a statement like this:

>  CREATE INDEX idx_ex1 ON ex1(a,b,c,d,e,...,y,z);
Then the index might be used if the initial columns of the index (columns a, b, and so forth) appear in WHERE clause terms. The initial columns of the index must be used with the = or IN operators. The right-most column that is used can employ inequalities. For the right-most column of an index that is used, there can be up to two inequalities that must sandwich the allowed values of the column between two extremes.

Comment: actually, I find another way to solve this problem. that is trying to decrease the count of 'strN'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [instr](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#instr) function is SQLite’s equivalent of `indexOf`.

Alternatively, you could use something like [LIKE](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#like):

```
SELECT *
  FROM table
 WHERE '#str1#str2#str3#' LIKE '%#' || data || '#%'
```

...but I **really** doubt that would be faster.

Note that the comparison string should both start *and* end with the separator (#), if you dont' want to match `data` as substring, but always as entire string.

You’ll probably want to try both to see which is faster.

Comment: I know that, but I also doubted the LIKE as u did. I'm trying now.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should be possible using [LIKE](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#like):

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE 'str1#str2#str3#str4#str5......' LIKE '%' + data + '%'
```

(SQL Server syntax but gives the general idea)